# Writing down to next cell using openpyxl

Tags: openpyxl

[image]

I am using python get data from an api trying to get a process, host name, start time of the process, user name, ip address, domain, and time stamp of each connection. Each process can have multiple results for the following columns that needs to move down each row. What is happening is that everything is being written into Row 2 as it gets over written. Here is my script.

```py
wb = Workbook()
ws1 = wb.create_sheet("Sheet_A")
ws1.title = "Results"
ws1['A1'] = "Process"
ws1['B1'] = "Host Name"
ws1['C1'] = "Process Time"
ws1['D1'] = "User Name"
ws1['E1'] = "Domain"
ws1['F1'] = "Netconn Time"

c = CbResponseAPI()

rows = 1

base_query = c.select(Process).where('start:-500m (hostname:1 OR hostname:2 OR hostname:3 OR hostname:4) netconn_count:[1 TO *] -ipaddr:192.168.0.0/16 -ipaddr:10.0.0.0/8 -ipaddr:172.16.0.0/12 -ipaddr:127.0.0.1')

for proc in base_query:
        # print proc
        ws1['A2'] = proc.process_name
        ws1['B2'] = proc.hostname
        ws1['C2'] = proc.start
        ws1['D2'] = proc.username
        rows+=1
        for netconn in proc.netconns:
            ws1['E2'] = netconn.domain
            ws1['F2'] = netconn.timestamp
            ws1['G2'] = netconn.remote_ip
            rows+=1

wb.save('Rav.xlsx')
```

[image: This is the end result of the script just one row, I should have thousands]

Here is my edit

```
for i, proc in enumerate(base_query):
        # print proc
        ws1[f'A{i+2}'] = proc.process_name
        ws1[f'B{i+2}'] = proc.hostname
        ws1[f'C{i+2}'] = proc.start
        ws1[f'D{i+2}'] = proc.username
        rows+=1
        for netconn in proc.netconns:
            ws1[f'E{i+2}'] = netconn.domain
            ws1[f'F{i+2}'] = netconn.timestamp
            ws1[f'G{i+2}'] = netconn.remote_ip
            rows+=1
```

Here is the output of print(proc) and print(netconn)

```
process_md5          : f8d0c92070e59a059a889d5e269c0da9
sensor_id            : 656
filtering_known_dlls : False
modload_count        : 45
parent_unique_id     : 00000290-0000-023c-01d5-e25a6a09eddc-000000000001
cmdline              : C:\Windows\ADWS\Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.WebServices.exe
last_update          : 2020-02-17 14:48:26.878000
id                   : 00000290-0000-0760-01d5-e25a77d2e409
parent_name          : services.exe
group                : default group
parent_id            : 00000290-0000-023c-01d5-e25a6a09eddc
hostname             : 
filemod_count        : 0
start                : 2020-02-13 10:43:46.254000
comms_ip             : 0.0.0.0
regmod_count         : 5
interface_ip         : 10.140.51.10
process_pid          : 1888
username             : SYSTEM
process_sha256       : d40478a82bb2993f39a3ed6066cd0599be37ff9a0898636a680926fe145c64d6
terminated           : False
emet_config          :
process_name         : microsoft.activedirectory.webservices.exe
emet_count           : 0
last_server_update   : 2020-02-17 14:49:19.877000
path                 : c:\windows\adws\microsoft.activedirectory.webservices.exe
netconn_count        : 12008
parent_pid           : 572
crossproc_count      : 11
segment_id           : 1581950959796
host_type            : domain_controller
processblock_count   : 0
os_type              : windows
childproc_count      : 0
unique_id            : 00000290-0000-0760-01d5-e25a77d2e409-017053a000b4
Cb Network Connection event:
timestamp            : 2020-02-17 14:44:26.844000
domain               :
remote_ip            : ::1
remote_port          : 389
proto                : IPPROTO_TCP
direction            : Outbound
local_ip             : ::1
local_port           : 52995
proxy_ip             : 0.0.0.0
proxy_port           : 0
```

Comment: Thanks for updating your code. Can you also please show result of `print(proc)` and your error trace back? Thank you

Comment: Why not just use the API that openpyxl provides?

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: Python Version 2.7.15

Answer (score 0):

You just need to [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) the `for` loop to give yourself a counter, to move to the next line. Then add 2 to `i` because you're starting on `row` 2, and `i` will start at `0`.

```py
for i, proc in enumerate(base_query):
        # print proc
        ws1[f'A{i+2}'] = proc.process_name
        ws1[f'B{i+2}'] = proc.hostname
        ws1[f'C{i+2}'] = proc.start
        ws1[f'D{i+2}'] = proc.username
        for netconn in proc.netconns:
            ws1[f'E{i+2}'] = netconn.domain
            ws1[f'F{i+2}'] = netconn.timestamp
            ws1[f'G{i+2}'] = netconn.remote_ip

wb.save('Rav.xlsx')
```

Here's my working example:

```py
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = Workbook()
ws1 = wb.create_sheet("Sheet_A")
ws1.title = "Results"
ws1['A1'] = "Process"
ws1['B1'] = "Host Name"
ws1['C1'] = "Process Time"
ws1['D1'] = "User Name"
ws1['E1'] = "Domain"
ws1['F1'] = "Netconn Time"


loop = [['process_name', 'hostname'],['process_name', 'hostname'],['process_name', 'hostname'],]

for i, proc in enumerate(loop):
        # print proc
        ws1[f'A{i+2}'] = proc[0]
        ws1[f'B{i+2}'] = proc[1]

wb.save('Rav.xlsx')
```

**Output**

[image: Excel Output]

Comment: I am getting invalid syntax on the '] on the first ws{f'

Comment: You're probably missing a character, can you please post your adjusted code?

Comment: It should be `ws1[f'` not the curly bracket `ws{f'`